# 6 Professors and 8 floors - expected value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this problem I need help with. There are 6 professors on an elevator that has 8 floors/stops. Each professors exits the elevator randomly(1/8 chance). What is the **expected value E(X)** of stops

(Right answer/Spoiler)

> circ. 4,4

So I know that I have to calculate possibility for every number of stops $P(X=k), k=1,...,6$ and then get expected value with this formula?

\begin{equation}
E(X) = \sum^6_{k=1}k \cdot P(X=k)
\end{equation}

But I have some problems with combinatorics... I know that
\begin{equation}
P(X=1) = \left(\frac 18\right) ^ 6 \cdot 8
\end{equation}

but further on I'm lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let  $X_i =\begin{cases}
  1   &\text{if the elevator stops on floor i} ,\\
  0   &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Then
$E(X_i) = P(X_i = 1) = 1 - (7/8)^6$

so

$E(\sum_{i=1}^8 X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^8 E(X_i) = 8 \; [1 - (7/8)^6]$

Comment: This method is much easier than Graham's. And it works because integration (expected value) is linear, regardless of independence.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that :)

Comment: Indeed. It's a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the probability that all professors stop on the same floor is:

$$P(X=1) = \frac 1 {8^6}{8\choose 1}{6\choose 6}$$

This is by counting ways to stop on the same floor by choosing floors to stop at, and professors to stop at each, out of the total of $8^6$ ways the professors might stop at floors.

Now extending that logic:

$$\begin{align}
P(X=2) & = \frac{1}{8^6}{8\choose 2}(2{6\choose 5,1}+2{6\choose 4,2}+{6\choose 3,3})
\\[1ex]
P(X=3) & = \frac{1}{8^6}{8\choose 3}(3{6\choose 4,1,1}+6{6\choose 3,2,1}+{6\choose 2,2,2})
\end{align}$$...and so forth...

Comment: That's a whole lot of complicated computation. Can you calculate this sort of thing effectively?

Comment: Just what i was asking for, it was very challenging

Comment: @GrahamKemp can i just ask why don't you vary(multiply by 2) between professor when there are let's say 2 floors and three of them go out on each floor?

Comment: @STAŠHVALA Because the series is counting the ways to divide the professors into two non-empty groups; one for the lower floor and one for the higher floor. ${6\choose 5}{1\choose 1} + {6\choose 4}{2\choose 2} + \color{blue}{{6\choose 3}{3\choose 3}} + {6\choose 2}{4\choose 4} + {6\choose 1}{5\choose 5}$

Comment: Now i get it, tnx :)